# A request to get a Twitter feed like?

Tags: mysql, sql

How does Twitter (or Facebook) do to retrieve a user feed?

Here is the database schema I am working on. I renamed everything to look like twitter hoping that the most of you would understand my question...

I only have two resources: `users` and `tweets`. So here are those two tables:

```
users:
    - id
    - username
tweets:
    - id
    - author_id
    - content
```

Let's continue with a simple pivot table to associate tweets and users:

```
user_tweet:
    - user_id
    - tweet_id
    - created_at
```

This pivot table is here mainly to store the `retweets`. But it also stores the original tweets for more convenience.

For example, let's take `user 1` tweets `'something'`. `user 2` and `user 3` retweet. The `user_tweet` table will have three rows.

And, let's see a last table that complicates everything: The Following System. 
Every user can follow an other user. I named the table "followee_follower":

```
followee_follower:
   - followee_id
   - follower_id
```

The **followee_id** is the `user.id` of **the person being followed**

The **follower_id** is the `user.id` of **the person that follows an other one**

Now let's get to the SQL problem:

I'm `user 1`. I follow `user 2`, and `user 3`. 
How can I retrieve the **tweets and retweets** from `user 2` and `user3` knowing that I want to retrieve them ordering them by the `created_at` field of the `user_tweet` table, and that I don't want to get two similar tweets.

Many thanks, any help is highly nice from you,

Have a good day/night.

**EDIT: Here are some samples data from tables:**

1. users table

[image: users table]

2. tweets table

[image: tweets table]

3. user_tweet table

[image: user_tweet table]

4. followee_follower table

[image: followee_follower table]

5. expected results

[image: expected results]

Comment: Why do I get a downvote :( ?

Comment: I took a guess at what you might be after, but sample data and desired results would be helpful to know for sure.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am formatting some sample data and expected output right now :) , and testing the answer you provided of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understand your question (sample data would help), but I think you just need to use multiple `joins`:

```
select t.id, t.content, ut.created_at
from tweets t
   inner join user_tweets ut on t.id = ut.tweet_id 
   inner join followee_follower ff on ut.user_id = ff.follower_id
where ff.followee_id = 1
order by ut.created_at
```

---

Perhaps if a user retweets, you'd want to do something like this instead to get the first tweet (assuming the id and created_at fields both should return the minimum):

```
select t.content, min(t.id), min(ut.created_at) 
from tweets t
   inner join user_tweets ut on t.id = ut.tweet_id 
   inner join followee_follower ff on ut.user_id = ff.follower_id
where ff.followee_id = 1
group by t.content
order by min(ut.created_at)
```

Comment: Problem solved with your code, I juste changed it a little, like the following:
```
select  t.id, t.content, max(ut.created_at) 
from tweets t
   inner join user_tweets ut on t.id = ut.tweet_id 
   inner join followee_follower ff on ut.user_id = ff.followee_id
where ff.follower_id = 1
group by t.id
order by max(ut.created_at) desc
```
But you were perfectly right with the use of min() and max() functions, thanks a lot! Could you edit your answer with this code so I can check it to "validate" ? Again, thanks a lot! I spent my entire night on it :)